# Running a PHP file out of the browser

Tags: php, matlab, web, browser

I am running a php file from MATLAB using these commands

```
url = 'http://www.mathworks.com';
[stat,h] = web(url);
close(h);
```

I was wonder that is there any possibility to run PHP files without opening  browser or running on the browser in some way hidden to the user.

Comment: yes you can via command, or terminal. just run "php /path/to/file.php"

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/example--reading-a-url.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: Where are you running a PHP file in that code? It's just downloading from a website.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, write your php code in a file:

**example.php**:

```
<?php
echo "Hello world"
?>
```

Then in your MATLAB write:

```
php_commandline = '"path/to/php/binary" example.php';
[status, result] = system(php_commandline);
```

I hope this helps